# convert .ps to .pcx using ghostscript

Tags: ghostscript

What is the command to convert a simulation.ps file with multiple pages to separate .pcx files using ghostscript on windows 7. I tried the following command:

cd c:\Program Files\gs\gs\9.06\bin

gswin32c -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pcx24b –g1024x768 -sOutputFile=simulation%%04d.pcx simulation.ps

I got the following output:

GPL Ghostscript 9.06 (2012-08-08)
Copyright (c) 2012 Artifex Software, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
This software comes with NO WARRANTY: see the file PUBLIC for details.
Loading NimusSanL-Regu font from %rom%Resoruce/Font/NimbusSanL-Regu... 2637176 1249969 2756072 1473902 1 done.

There was no files created in the c:\Program Files\gs\gs\9.06\bin\ directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with just one '%' sign instead of 2. Other than that, your command line works for me (I substituted the golfer EPS file for your 'simlation.ps')

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I removed the % sign in the command line, but the error still persists. This seems to be an issue with the file and not with ghostscript.

Comment: If you can share an example I can look into it, you should at least get a blank page